# Programming logic for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, logic

I have the following numbers : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...

I have a number n, say `n=2`, then i want arrays divided with those many numbers, that is :

```
For `n=2`
Result array : 1,2, 5,6, 9,10, 13,14, ... <br />
Result array 2 : 3,4, 7,8, 11,12 ...

For `n=3`
Result array : 1,2,3, 7,8,9, ... <br />
Result array 2 : 4,5,6, 10,11,12...
```

I cannot seem to get even the logic for this. 
I tried searching for something similar on google , however couldn't get it. 
Please help.

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you using a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, I was trying with for loops and a set of modulus combinations.
I guess the answer by @Truth should work.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the accepted answer what you wanted, or do you want the result as you showed in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not totally clear how you want the chunked output divided between two arrays but you can get most of the way there by using the JavaScript core [Array `slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```javascript
function chunk(arr, n) {
  var a=[], i;
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i += n) {
    a.push(arr.slice(i, i+n));
  }
  return a;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
chunk(a, 2) # => [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12]]
chunk(a, 3) # => [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
chunk(a, 5) # => [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12]]
```

Here's how you can put those results into two arrays, exactly per your question:

```
function chunk2(arr, n) {
  var a1=[], a2=[], a=a1, len=arr.length, i;
  for (i=0; i<len; i+=n, a=(a===a1?a2:a1)) {
    a.push(arr.slice(i, i+n));
  }
  return [a1, a2];
}
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var x = chunk2(a, 2);
x[0]; // => [[1,2], [5,6], [9,10]]
x[1]; // => [[3,4], [7,8], [11,12]]
x = chunk2(a, 3);
x[0]; // => [[1,2,3], [7,8,9]]
x[1]; // => [[4,5,6], [10,11,12]]
```

Comment: That doesn't divide the items into two arrays, as the example shows.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_chunk (input, size, preserve_keys) {
    // Split array into chunks  
    // 
    // version: 1109.2015
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_chunk
    // +   original by: Carlos R. L. Rodrigues (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // %        note 1: Important note: Per the ECMAScript specification, objects may not always iterate in a predictable order
    // *     example 1: array_chunk(['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld'], 2);
    // *     returns 1: [['Kevin', 'van'], ['Zonneveld']]
    // *     example 2: array_chunk(['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld'], 2, true);
    // *     returns 2: [{0:'Kevin', 1:'van'}, {2: 'Zonneveld'}]
    // *     example 3: array_chunk({1:'Kevin', 2:'van', 3:'Zonneveld'}, 2);
    // *     returns 3: [['Kevin', 'van'], ['Zonneveld']]
    // *     example 4: array_chunk({1:'Kevin', 2:'van', 3:'Zonneveld'}, 2, true);
    // *     returns 4: [{1: 'Kevin', 2: 'van'}, {3: 'Zonneveld'}]

    var x, p = '', i = 0, c = -1, l = input.length || 0, n = [];

    if (size < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Array]') {
        if (preserve_keys) {
            while (i < l) {
                (x = i % size) ? n[c][i] = input[i] : n[++c] = {}, n[c][i] = input[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            while (i < l) {
                (x = i % size) ? n[c][x] = input[i] : n[++c] = [input[i]];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (preserve_keys) {
            for (p in input) {
                if (input.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    (x = i % size) ? n[c][p] = input[p] : n[++c] = {}, n[c][p] = input[p];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (p in input) {
                if (input.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    (x = i % size) ? n[c][x] = input[p] : n[++c] = [input[p]];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Taken from **[here](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_chunk:306)**. Which was one of the first results when searching **javascript array chunks**.

Comment: Thanks a ton!
I was searching with terms like 'array set output', 'using modulus to seprate loops', never got any good results with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the items into two arrays like this:

```
function chunk(arr, cnt) {
  var result = [[],[]];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) result[Math.floor(i / cnt) % 2].push(arr[i]);
  return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/t7agt/